# Cannot Generate Pokemon names in Dropdown List

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap, array.prototype.map, pokeapi

So I'm re-visiting an old bootcamp project that I had to give up because I was getting too close to the deadline and not enough progress made.

Working with the Pokemon API: I'm just try to create a dropdown component (via react-bootstrap dropdown component) to just generate a list of Pokemon names fetched from the API.  The dropdown seems to generate the right amount of entries, but the names do not actually show up in the dropdown.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
// import PokemonList from './components/PokemonList';

function App() {
  
  // Axios fetch call
  const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon';
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      setPokemons(response.data.results)
      console.log(response.data.results)
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Dropdown>
        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
          Dropdown Button
        </Dropdown.Toggle>

        <Dropdown.Menu>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
      <br />
      <Dropdown>
          <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
            List of Pokemon
          </Dropdown.Toggle>
          
          <Dropdown.Menu>
            {pokemons.map((pokemon => {
              return <Dropdown.Item href="#" key={pokemon}>{pokemons.name}</Dropdown.Item>
              }))}
          </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
      {/* <PokemonList pokemons={pokemons} /> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `{pokemons.name}` should be `{pokemon.name}`.

Comment: Seems like you're using the wrong variable, it should be pokemon.name not pokemons.name

Comment: *sigh*  Thanks....that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the variable to the correct one, but also went ahead and built more code to capitalize the first letter of each name:

```
{pokemons.map((pokemon => {
    return <Dropdown.Item href="#" key={pokemon}>{pokemon.name[0].toUpperCase() + pokemon.name.substring(1)}</Dropdown.Item>
              }))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few mistakes in the code. The first one being the most obvious that you are trying to access the property `name` from the `pokemons` instead of `pokemon` that you are mapping over.

```
<Dropdown.Menu>
            {pokemons && pokemons.map((pokemon,idx) => {
              const name = pokemon.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pokemon.name.slice(1);
              return <Dropdown.Item eventkey={idx} key={idx}>{name}</Dropdown.Item>
              })}
</Dropdown.Menu>
```

Then you are also setting the initial state to be an empty array but you can just leave it empty as you are already setting state to be an array of objects.

```
const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState();
```

### Output:

[image]

[Link to working Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-mountain-busg8?file=/src/App.js)